# can not find list control in SharePoint 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I have created a list in top level site. And I want to use the list in a child site (e.g. adding the list to a page in child site by using Page --> Add Web Parts --> Browse), but can not find the list created in parent site in this way. Any ideas how to use the list (created in parent site) in a child site?

BTW: I can use the list (created in parent site) in parent site without any issues.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to do a cross-site lookup, which you won't get in the default web parts. If you have designer, you could use the data view web part. Alternately, there are a few third-party web parts out there that will do what you want; Bamboo Solutions springs to mind.

Comment: 1. I am confused. If I create a custom web part using data sheet view in parent web site, I can not use it in child site in SharePoint design? 2. "If you have designer, you could use the data view web part." -- how to use data view web part to create a list to be used in both parent site and child site? Could you show me how (any documents for this)?

Comment: You'd create the data view web part on your child site. You'll establish a data connection to the list on the parent site. Here's a pretty good overview, along with a video demo:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300164.aspx